# Python : Get size of string in bytes

Tags: python

I have a string that is to be sent over a network. I need to check the total bytes it is represented in.

`sys.getsizeof(string_name)` returns extra bytes. For example for `sys.getsizeof("a")` returns 22 , while one character is only represented in 1 byte in python. Is there some other method to find this ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: That's because the string "a" is an object in python that contains extra information.

Comment: @Some Developer is there a way to get bytes for the string only, without extra information of the complete object?

Comment: @squiguy My python version is 2.7.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine the byte length of a utf-8 encoded string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714826/how-can-i-determine-the-byte-length-of-a-utf-8-encoded-string-in-python)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

If you want the number of bytes in a string, this function should do it for you pretty solidly.

```
def utf8len(s):
    return len(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

The reason you got weird numbers is because encapsulated in a string is a bunch of other information due to the fact that strings are actual objects in python.

Its interesting because if you look at my solution to encode the string into 'utf-8', there's an 'encode' method on the 's' object (which is a string). Well, it needs to be stored somewhere right? Hence, the higher than normal byte count. Its including that method, along with a few others :).

Comment: No worries. Sometimes simple answers make their way into seemingly weird problems haha.

Comment: The reason for encoding is that, in Python 3, some single-character strings will require multiple bytes to be represented.  For instance: `len('你'.encode('utf-8'))`.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `len(s.encode())` but there's a caveat.

The size in bytes of a string depends on the encoding you choose (by default "utf-8").

For some multi-byte encodings (e.g. utf-16), `string.encode` will add a *Byte Order Mark* (BOM) at the start, which is a sequence of special bytes that inform the reader on the [byte endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) used. So the length you get is actually `len(BOM) + len(encoded_word)`.

If you don't want to count the BOM bytes, you can use either the little-endian version of the encoding (adding the suffix "-le") or the big-endian version (adding the suffix "be").

```
>>> len('ciao'.encode('utf-16'))
10
>>> len('ciao'.encode('utf-16-le'))
8
```