# Check that textInput does not exceed 256 (dialogflow)

Tags: python-2.7, dialogflow-es

I send a query to dialogflow from python api and I got the error:

> Text length must not exceed 256 bytes.

I calculate lenght of my text like this :

```
l=len(Text)
```

But I still get the error that my texts exceed 256.
So I want to khow how to check that my text doesn't exceed 256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686701/python-get-size-of-string-in-bytes) (**len(Text.encode('utf-8'))**) should work better than just **len(Text)**.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That did it.